# Docker's mount breaks node.js

Tags: node.js, docker

I want to develop my Node.js server app inside a Docker container so I don't have to install dependencies like databases, etc.

I have a Dockerfile that looks like this:

```
FROM node:9.7
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN yarn
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

And I run my container after building an image in Docker like this:

```
docker run \
    -v ~/folder-name:/app \
    -p 8080:8080 \
    image-name
```

And I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
```

If I remove the `-v` flag then it works just fine. Seems like the process of mounting a folder get in the way of working Node.js.

How do I approach developing a Node.js app inside Docker so that it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to either use `COPY` in your Dockerfile or mount your app as a volume inside the Docker container, not both for the same directory.

`COPY` will only get your app files upon container creation and won't bother with your local files afterwards during the lifetime of that container.
`Volume` will mount your local folder into the docker container, thus it will keep up to date with your local changes.

Since you want to develop your app using Docker you will want to use a volume mount, so when you change your files they get pulled into the container automatically.

Also you probably want to use [Nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) to automatically restart the application upon file changes. To do this you can install nodemon globally from your Dockerfile and then start your app using it.

Example Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest
LABEL Name=my-app Version=1.0.0
RUN npm install -g nodemon --silent
RUN npm install --production --silent
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 8080
VOLUME ["/usr/src/app"]
CMD nodemon index.js
```

Comment: If I mount without `COPY` then how do I deploy to prod? Should I also mount a folder with code on production too?

Comment: also, `npm install` (or `yarn`) will not work during build if I don't `COPY`

Comment: You always need to have the code on a production server, whether it be mounted or copied into the container. Mounting a volume is preferred for development as stated in the answer, whereas you might prefer copying in prod since it will manage file rights for you.

Comment: I did as you advised but still used `COPY` to copy several configs, namely `package.json` and `tsconfig.json`. Otherwise image won't build.